# Use-Cases for a "Silicon Serial Number" IC

Tags: production, serial-number

I recently came across this [Silicon Serial Number IC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ds2401.pdf).

Now, I understand the purpose and usefulness of serial numbers in products.

However, I don't understand why one would not simply place a serial number generated during programming in some FLASH/EEPROM.

My question, therefore, is: In which applications is such an IC used, and why can these applications not store the serial number in a more 'common way'?

Comment: Can be erased...acidentally or on purpose.

Answer (score 7):

If you weren't planning on putting in memory devices, this would save you the non-trivial hassle of programming chips with a single number either off-board and populating them (or having your fab house do it - $$$) or putting the programming "infrastructure" on your board, which you will use once.

It's also a good deal harder to spoof or tamper with this serial number. I won't say "impossible" since you can buy a 1-wire ROM chip, program it with any serial number you like, and swap it onto the board but it's more secure than putting it in perhaps user-accessible EEPROM and hoping your firmware doesn't allow access somehow. Finally, this device makes it far less less likely (or someone else's fault in any case) for a misconfiguration to give two devices the same serial number - one of those things that sound like you would never do until you get devices back from the field, check your code, and go "oh".

Answer (score 5):

In some application fields, you need to guarantee that a device can be completely "wiped" so that it contains no memory of anything it encountered during operation, I.e., offer a *certificate of volatility*. That of course gets easier to do if there's one less programmable component!

I'm sure there's even fields where even just having memory is problematic for certification, or where mask ROM is preferable due to radiation hardness.